# Selectinput enable or disable actionbuttons - has problems

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have found a solution but there is something wrong with my code.

I find this solution from **shinyjs package**

The former question you can have a view here

[How to deal with this: A input window and 2 or more actionbutton but different input selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666668/how-to-deal-with-this-a-input-window-and-2-or-more-actionbutton-but-different-i)

##########

**Here is my code that is not completely.**

```
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
library(stats)
library(openxlsx)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)      
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)  ##  inline the all the plot
library(ggpubr)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinymanager)
library(psych)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

# Prepare dataset.
#   1. Bind mean and sd data
#   2. Reshape
data <- bind_rows(list(
  mean = mean_data,
  sd = sd_data
), .id = "stat")
data_mean_sd <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Name, stat), names_to = "Gene", values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "stat", values_from = "value")


data_mean_sd2<-data_mean_sd[data_mean_sd$Gene==paste0("Gene_",1:25),]

###
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           h2("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           selectInput(
             "selectGeneSymbol", 
             "Select Gene Symbol:", 
             choices = unique(data_mean_sd$Gene),
             multiple =F,
             width = 800,
             selected = "Igfbp7"
           ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM",width=80),
           actionButton(inputId = "plot2", label = "LogFc",width=80),
           actionButton(inputId = "all",label = "FPKM&LogFc",width=120)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           uiOutput("all")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$plot2,input$all, {
    if(input$selectGeneSymbol %in% unique(data_mean_sd2$Gene)){
      shinyjs::enable("plot2")
      shinyjs::enable("all")
    }else{
      shinyjs::disable("plot2")
      shinyjs::disable("all")
    }
  })
  
  plot_data1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
    subset(data_mean_sd, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  plot_data2 <- eventReactive(input$plot2, { 
    subset(data_mean_sd2, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL)
  

  
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot1", height=600)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot2", height=600)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$all, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot3", height=800)
  })
  
  
  output$all <- renderUI({
    global$out
  })
  
  p1 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot1,
                           input$all), {
    ggplot(data = plot_data1(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)) 
  })  
  
  p2 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot2,
                           input$all), {
    ggplot(data = plot_data2(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)) 
  })  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ p1() })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({ p2() })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({ grid.arrange(p1(),p2(), ncol=1) })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run my code:

**The error :**

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Can somebody help me ?

**EDIT:2021-03-17 17:26:03：**

**I  have improved my code just now and it can work better but not perfect.
Just like this:**

```
 observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    if(input$selectGeneSymbol %in% unique(data_mean_sd2$Gene)){
      shinyjs::enable("plot2")
      global$out <- plotOutput("plot2", height=600)
      
    }else{
      shinyjs::disable("plot2")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$all, {
    if(input$selectGeneSymbol %in% unique(data_mean_sd2$Gene)){
      shinyjs::enable("all")
      global$out <- plotOutput("plot3", height=800)
      
    }else{
      shinyjs::disable("all")
    }
    
  })
```

**The actionbutton can be disabled if somebody inputs a gene symbol if it is only in data_mean_sd2.

But I met a new problem is that the disabled actionbutton keep disabled though I select a new gene. So I have to modify my code next step.**

Comment: Your code has many fundamental errors.  For example, your `output$plot1` (and `plot2` and `plot3`) is trying to render an `eventReactive` as a plot. Setting an element of a `reactiveValues` object to `NULL` removes the element from the `reactiveValues` object.  Your code is not an MWE.

Comment: @Limey Yeah,thanks for your advice. You know it's just my sample code. 

And I  modified my code just now. It works well in some degree. I still have the last problem that need your help before I could solve it by myself.

Comment: @YBS   master, please do me a favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           h2("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           selectInput(
             "selectGeneSymbol", 
             "Select Gene Symbol:", 
             choices = unique(data_mean_sd$Gene),
             multiple =F,
             width = 800,
             selected = "Igfbp7"
           ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM",width=80),
           actionButton(inputId = "plot2", label = "LogFc",width=80),
           actionButton(inputId = "all",label = "FPKM&LogFc",width=120)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           uiOutput("plots")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$selectGeneSymbol, {
    if(sum(unique(data_mean_sd2$Gene) %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)>0) {
      shinyjs::enable("plot2")
      shinyjs::enable("all")
    }else{
      shinyjs::disable("plot2")
      shinyjs::disable("all")
    }
  })
  
  plot_data1 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot1,input$all), { 
    subset(data_mean_sd, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  plot_data2 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot2,input$all), { 
    subset(data_mean_sd2, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  global <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(list(input$plot1,input$all), {
               req(plot_data1())
  #p1 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot1,
  #                         input$all), {
                global$p1 <- ggplot(data = plot_data1(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
                               geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                               geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
                               theme_classic2() +
                               rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
                               theme(legend.position = "none") +
                               labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
                               theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
                               theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
                               theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)) 
                           })  
  
  observeEvent(list(input$plot2,input$all), {
               req(plot_data2())
  #p2 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot2,
  #                         input$all), {
                global$p2 <- ggplot(data = plot_data2(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
                               geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                               geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
                               theme_classic2() +
                               rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
                               theme(legend.position = "none") +
                               labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
                               theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
                               theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
                               theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)) 
                           })  
  
  output$plt1 <- renderPlot({ global$p1 })
  output$plt2 <- renderPlot({ global$p2 })
  output$plt3 <- renderPlot({ grid.arrange(global$p1,global$p2, ncol=1) })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plt1", height=600)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plt2", height=600)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$all, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plt3", height=800)
  })
  
  
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    global$out
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Oh,my god, honey, so grateful. So preciate  it.

Comment: @花落思量错, If this has resolved your issue of enable or disable actionButton, please consider accepting the answer as it helps others.

Comment: Yeah ,I accepted your answer just now. Thanks.