# How to avoid error messages by output attention text in mainpanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I creat a shinyapp and there is only one selectinput box.And there are two vital actionbutton.

The first button uses the `data_mean_sd` and the second button uses the `data_mean_sd2`.

But I met a problem that when I select one gene which exists in  `data_mean_sd` but not in `data_mean_sd2` and then click the second button the error message may appear.

So I get a better answer from @YBS. Here:
[Selectinput enable or disable actionbuttons - has problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66668777/selectinput-enable-or-disable-actionbuttons-has-problems)

**## My question is:**
Now I want to use another solution when I choose one gene that only included in `data_mean_sd` and click second button **I hope the attention text could output in mainpanel just like: the gene you select is not contained or not found.**

I find a solution came from https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html Write error messages for your UI with validate.

But I think there must be other better solution to my question.

**If I can only modify the part code below?**

```
  observeEvent(input$selectGeneSymbol, {
    if(sum(unique(data_mean_sd2$Gene) %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)>0) {
      shinyjs::enable("plot2")
      shinyjs::enable("all")
    }else{
      shinyjs::disable("plot2")
      shinyjs::disable("all")
    }
  })
```

I hope somebody could give me some advice.Vary thankful.

Here is my reproducible code and data:

```
mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

# Prepare dataset.
#   1. Bind mean and sd data
#   2. Reshape
data <- bind_rows(list(
  mean = mean_data,
  sd = sd_data
), .id = "stat")
data_mean_sd <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Name, stat), names_to = "Gene", values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "stat", values_from = "value")


data_mean_sd2<-data_mean_sd[data_mean_sd$Gene==paste0("Gene_",1:25),]

###
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           h2("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           selectInput(
             "selectGeneSymbol", 
             "Select Gene Symbol:", 
             choices = unique(data_mean_sd$Gene),
             multiple =F,
             width = 800,
             selected = "123"
           ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM",width=80),
           actionButton(inputId = "plot2", label = "LogFc",width=80),
           actionButton(inputId = "all",label = "FPKM&LogFc",width=120)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           uiOutput("plots")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$selectGeneSymbol, {
    if(sum(unique(data_mean_sd2$Gene) %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)>0) {
      shinyjs::enable("plot2")
      shinyjs::enable("all")
    }else{
      shinyjs::disable("plot2")
      shinyjs::disable("all")
    }
  })
  
  plot_data1 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot1,input$all), { 
    subset(data_mean_sd, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  plot_data2 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot2,input$all), { 
    subset(data_mean_sd2, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  global <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(list(input$plot1,input$all), {
               req(plot_data1())
  #p1 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot1,
  #                         input$all), {
                global$p1 <- ggplot(data = plot_data1(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
                               geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                               geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
                               theme_classic2() +
                               rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
                               theme(legend.position = "none") +
                               labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
                               theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
                               theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
                               theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)) 
                           })  
  
  observeEvent(list(input$plot2,input$all), {
               req(plot_data2())
  #p2 <- eventReactive(list(input$plot2,
  #                         input$all), {
                global$p2 <- ggplot(data = plot_data2(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
                               geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                               geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
                               theme_classic2() +
                               rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
                               theme(legend.position = "none") +
                               labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
                               theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
                               theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
                               theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)) 
                           })  
  
  output$plt1 <- renderPlot({ global$p1 })
  output$plt2 <- renderPlot({ global$p2 })

  
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plt1", height=600)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plt2", height=600)
  })
  
  
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    global$out
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @YBS Sir, I need your help.

Comment: @YBS ,I solved it by myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so excited that I solved this problem by myself.

The vital part of my solution is finding answer from https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html

Just as the official documentation said here:
[image]

So I put the `validate()` function in my `renderPlot()` like this:

```
  output$plt2 <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(sum(unique(colnames(data_mean_sd2[,-1])) %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)>0, "Error information you personal customized.")
    )
    p2() 
    })
```

And it works well.
Don't forget deleting the code below and the related information.

```
  observeEvent(input$selectGeneSymbol, {
    if(sum(unique(data_mean_sd2$Gene) %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)>0) {
      shinyjs::enable("plot2")
      shinyjs::enable("all")
    }else{
      shinyjs::disable("plot2")
      shinyjs::disable("all")
    }
  })
```

Comment: That is great!  You can also try `showModal()` if you want to display a pop-up message with the error.